# Binarize the ratings - MovieLens dataset

Tags: dataset, recommendation-engine, mahout-recommender, collaborative-filtering

I am working on a personalised news recommendation engine based on click-behaviour of users. My features will be **predefined news categories** *(such as politics, sport and etc).*

Whenever user clicks on an article, I build/update user profile based on this article, then recommend another article from articles pool.

Regarding evaluation of this system, I need to have a dataset which contains binary user-item interactions (user clicked on recommended article or not) - which I couldn't find an appropriate dataset for this specific context. What I'm trying to do is, binarize Movielens dataset, then calculate precision and recall.

What I actually do in MovieLens dataset is as follows: **if the rating for an item, by a user, is larger than the average rating by this user I assign it a binary rating of 1, 0 otherwise.**

Is this approach right way to evaluate such kind of systems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. binarizing makes no difference. Precision and recall are relative so the fact that someone rated is all you need. The algo for a "good" rating is meaningless for testing purposes.
2. epinions has two dataset, one for ratings, the other binary for trust.
3. use MAP@k mean average precision for some number of recommendations. This will take account of the ranking in a group of recommendations, which is no, doubt how they will be used.

BTW there is already a recommender in open source that does this, and allows mixing multiple events/actions/indicators and can also use content similarity [here](https://templates.prediction.io/PredictionIO/template-scala-parallel-universal-recommendation). It is based on PredictionIO's framework, which is Spark based.